# Share Git and SSH config between Windows 10 and WSL2

Tags: git, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, putty, git-for-windows

I have Putty and Git installed on Windows 10, and I'm also using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Sometimes I want to use SSH and Git from WSL2, other times in Windows. Everything works fine, except I have to duplicate my `.gitconfig`, `.gitignore` and `.ssh` files in both my Windows and WSL2 home directories.

I don't want to maintain this config in two places, so I thought I could symlink the files in WSL2:

```sh
# In /home/myuser on WSL2
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/myuser/.ssh
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/myuser/.gitconfig
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/myuser/.gitignore
```

This kind of works, except for a few problems.

1. Files in `/mnt/c` have `0777` permissions and `chmod` obviously doesn't do anything on them. When I use `ssh` in WSL2, it complains about the key: `Permissions 0777 for '/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open`
2. In `.gitconfig` I have `core.excludesfile` set to `C:\\\\Users\\myuser\\.gitignore`, which works when using Git from Windows but not from WSL2. If I change it to `/home/myuser/.gitignore` it works in WSL2 but not on Windows. I tried using the relative path `.gitignore` and completely removing the `core.excludesfile` directive, but neither worked.

Does anyone know a work around to these issues? It did occur to me that Putty doesn't care about the SSH key permissions, so I could move the files to WSL2 and then update my Putty connections *(I have a lot of them!)* to access the keys via `\\wsl$`. However, that wouldn't solve the `core.excludesfile` problem and I'd prefer to maintain the config in Windows and access it in WSL2 via `/mnt/c`.

---

**Additional Context**

I'm converting my dev environment from Windows to WSL2, using PhpStorm and Docker for PHP development. I have switched Docker to use the WSL2 backend instead of Hyper-V and moved my project files (i.e. git repos) to WSL2. I then open the project in PhpStorm using the `\\wsl$` share. All of this is working great and I love how much faster it is, but having to duplicate the git config and ssh keys is annoying.

Comment: Since SSH keys should not change, I don't see any issue with keeping a copy inside the WSL2 distro? As for problem 2, I'm not aware of any solution - so you will probably have to keep a copy.

Comment: You can use a `~` in `core.excludesfile`.

Comment: @bk2204 Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think about that. I just assumed Windows wouldn't understand `~/.gitignore` but it works on both surprisingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I have found is to mount the windows ssh config folder over the WSL copy.

In your `/etc/fstab` in WSL1/2, add the corresponding entries:

```
# WSL 1 - mount C: with correct permissions, then bind mount .ssh
C:                              /mnt/c                  drvfs   rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off,umask=0077,fmask=0077 0 0
/mnt/c/Users/me/.ssh            /home/me/.ssh           none    bind,default    0 0
 
# WSL2
C:\Users\me\.ssh\        /home/me/.ssh    drvfs rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off,umask=0077,fmask=0177 0 0
```

Updating the usernames and UID/GID as needed.

Comment: This no-fuss solution worked for me. I'm now  using a single `~/.ssh/config` file for both 'hosts' (WSL and Windows).  I also have per-host customisations by using the SSH `Include` directive, where the path is host-specific.  E.g. to include WSL specific config, I use `Include /home/me/ssh_config.wsl`, where  Windows doesn't find that path.  (NOTE: I prefer this approach to modifying `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/`).  Thankyou @LarryH. FWIW, my failed attempts included: creating a Windows shortcut to point at my WSL .ssh, creating a WSL softlink to point at my Windows .ssh.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Idk why. I get: `<3>WSL (20471) ERROR: MountWithRetry:307: mount(drvfs, /home/me/.ssh, 9p, 0x00000400, cache=mmap,msize=262144,trans=virtio,aname=drvfs;path=/mnt/g/.ssh;uid=1000;gid=1000;case=off;umask=0077;fmask=0177;symlinkroot=/mnt/) failed: No such file or directory`. The mount is `/mnt/g/.ssh/ /home/me/.ssh drvfs rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off,umask=0077,fmask=0177 0 0`, where G: is a network drive mounted with `G: /mnt/g drvfs defaults 0 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the folder by putting the following code in your `~/.bashrc` file.

```bash
cp -r /mnt/c/Users/myuser/.ssh ~/.ssh_new \
  && rm -rf ~/.ssh \
  && mv ~/.ssh_new ~/.ssh \
  && chmod 700 ~/.ssh \
  && chmod 400 ~/.ssh/* \
  && chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts \
  && chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub
```